# How to adjust the word order of the following sentences to a more common style?

Tags: word-order

I read in a grammar text this sentence:
*Wir kränkelten;  krank (aber) durften wir nicht heißen.*

Leaving out the focal effect of *aber* from consideration, I am wondering which one of the following expresses a closer meaning to the original '**krank durften wir nicht heißen**' :
1. *wir durften nicht krank heißen.*
2. *wir durften krank nicht heißen.*

I am unsure whether *nicht* should **precede** *krank*, as in #1, or **follow** *krank*, as in #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is impossible; in particular, since the use of *heißen* is already old-fashioned and poetic, another oddity doesn’t feel too strange. The neutral word order, however, is that in the first sentence:

> Wir durften nicht krank heißen.

Comment: Thanks; did you mean that either alternative is acceptable?

Comment: Yes, for some definition of “acceptable”. :-) These sentences both sound poetic and somewhat odd. With a different verb, e.g. _Wir durften nicht krank sein_ and _Wir durften krank nicht sein_, you’d have one normal and one strange sentence.

Comment: The oddness comes from the normal contemporary usage of  "heissen", which goes with a name only (*Ich heisse Fritz*). It has, however, an aging meaning, that aligns more with "nennen" (*Jemanden einen Trottel heissen*)